# What do we know about $\displaystyle \frac{f}{\gcd(f,f')}$ if $f\in\mathbb{F}_{p^d}[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ and $f\in\mathbb{K}[X]$ be a non-constant polynomial with the factorization $$f=\prod_{i=1}^nf_i^{k_i}$$ where $f_i\in\mathbb{K}[X]$ is irreducible and $k_i\in\mathbb{N}$. Moreover, let $I:=\left\{i:p\nmid k_i\right\}$.

1. What can we say about $$g:=\frac{f}{\gcd(f,f')}$$
2. How do we show $$\frac{f}{\gcd(f,g^k)}=\prod_{i\notin I}f_i^{k_i}$$ for some $k\ge k_i$ for all $i\in I$?
3. What's the square-free part of $f$? May it be $g$?

With the given facts, it's easy to see that $$f'=\left(\prod_{i\in I}f_i^{k_i-1}\right)\sum_{i\in I}k_if_i'\prod_{j\in I\setminus{i}}f_j$$

How do we proceed for (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f=f_i^{k_i}h_i$ with $f_i\nmid h_i$ to determine the highest power of $f_i$ in $f'$s factorization. You will have to use the product rule to expand $f'$, and the answer will depend on whether or not $p\mid k_i$. Once you know the highest power of the $f_i$s appearing in $f'$s factorization, you will know $\gcd(f,f')$ and hence $g$. Once you see what $g$ is, you will be able to tell what $f/\gcd(f,g^k)$ is.

Comment: I've already used the product rule to expand $f'$. The result is shown in the last equation at the end of the question. There we can see, that the form of $f'$ depends on $p\mid k_i$.

Comment: @oxbadfood I meant use the product rule on $f=f_i^{k_i}h_i$. This will help you determine the highest power of $f_i$ in $f'$ for each $i$, which will give you $\gcd(f,f')$ (how?).

Comment: Oh, I see. We get $$f'=\begin{cases}f_i^{k_i-1}\left(k_if_i'h_i+f_ih_i'\right)&\text{, if }p\nmid k_i\\f_i^{k_i}h_i'&\text{, else}\end{cases}$$ So, the hightest power of $f_i$ in $f'$ is $$\begin{cases}k_i-1&\text{, if }p\nmid k_i\\k_i&\text{, else}\end{cases}$$ So far, so good?

Comment: @oxbardfood Correct.

Comment: So, it should follow $$\gcd(f,f')=\left(\prod_{i\in I}f_i^{k_i-1}\right)\prod_{i\notin I}f_i^{k_i}$$ Which yields $$g=\frac{f}{\gcd(f,f')}=\prod_{i\in I}f_i$$ This seems to make sense. What about $\gcd(f,g^k)$?

Comment: @oxbadfood Correct. How would you think about it if we were working with primes and natural numbers? It's the same thought process here. If $g\mid f$, then what does $\gcd(f,g^k)$ eventually become as $k$ increases?

Comment: We've got $\gcd(f,g)=g$. Since $g$ should be the square-free part of $f$, $\gcd(f,g^2)$ must be $g$ or some polynomial $h$ with $\deg h\in[\deg g,2\deg g)$. If $f$ were a natural number and $g$ a prime number, the $p$-adic order $$\nu _g(f)=\max\left\{k\in\mathbb{N}:g^k\mid f\right\}$$ would be something of interest.

Comment: @oxbadfood No, $g$ is not the squarefree part of $f$. If $g\mid f$, then what does $\gcd(f,g^k)$ eventually become? Think one prime at a time. Let $p$ be some prime divisor of $g$. What does the highest power of $p$ dividing $f$ and $g^k$ eventually become for $k$ large enough?